# A commutative diagram of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $\alpha:R\to R'$ an injective ring homomorphism. Let $K$ and $K'$ be the fields of fractions of $R$ and $R'$ respectively. I know that there is a commutative diagram of rings

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
R @>{\iota}>> K\\
@V{\alpha}VV @V{\beta}VV \\
R^\prime @>{\iota^\prime}>> K^\prime
\end{CD}$$

where $\iota$ and $\iota'$ are the canonical inclusion maps. Here $\beta$ can be defined by $\beta(r/s)=\alpha(r)/\alpha(s)$ for $r\in R$ and $s\in R-0$.

My question: is there a similar commutative diagram if we replace respectively $K$ and $K'$ by arbitrary extension fields $F$ and $F'$?

Many thanks.

Comment: What happens if you take $R = \Bbb Z, R' = \Bbb Q$ and $K = \Bbb Q[\sqrt{3}], K' = \Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$, with $\alpha = 1_{\Bbb Z}$? This satisfies your conditions, but defining $\beta$ is going to be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Note that $\beta$ must be injective, since it can't be $0$ and it's a field homomorphism, then take $R = R' = F'$ to be a finite field, and $F = R(t)$ to be the function field in one variable over $R$. Then $F$ is infinite and $F'$ is finite so $\beta$ cannot be injective.